# How does SVG image pattern work with preserving aspect ratio?

Tags: css, html, image, svg, web

I have the following svg:

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0;">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
      <image xlink:href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2016/06/22/gettyimages-467390112_custom-e8fa0c9a7224b7172555577fde25a08949bde2d2-s900-c85.jpg" x="0" y="-20" width="100" height="100"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="0 100, 50,50 100,100" id="abajo" style="stroke-width:0" fill="url(#img1)"/>
</svg>
```

It's not working as expected because it enlarge te face of the people on the image as follows:

[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

Does having a triangular polygon affects the image? How can I solve it, I need 4 triangle figures with images inside to be clickables.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a clipPath, not a pattern

Comment: I think clipPath will not work to achieve something like this http://headtag.mx/OP/ and doesn't have full support on Edge.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is working as intended. You specify a pattern whose unit should fill the bounding box of the container, and then specify a 2:1 container - so it stretches the image. There are lots of permutations that preserve the aspect ratio of the image - it depends on exactly what behavior you want.

This is one version that preserves the aspect ratio of the SVG itself even when it's asked to fill a larger space.

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0;">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2016/06/22/gettyimages-467390112_custom-e8fa0c9a7224b7172555577fde25a08949bde2d2-s900-c85.jpg" x="0" y="-20" width="100" height="100"/>
          </pattern>
    </defs>
        <polygon points="0 100, 50,50 100,100" id="abajo"  fill="url(#img1)" />
    </svg>
```

Or if you want to adjust the pattern itself, you can double the height of the pattern and offset it in Y to adjust for the 2:1 ratio of your container:

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100"  style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0;">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" y="-100%" width="100%" height="200%">
            <image xlink:href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2016/06/22/gettyimages-467390112_custom-e8fa0c9a7224b7172555577fde25a08949bde2d2-s900-c85.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"/>
          </pattern>
    </defs>
        <polygon points="0 100, 50,50 100,100" id="abajo"  fill="url(#img1)" />
    </svg>
```

This is another version that uses a filter to fill in the image.

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; background:grey">
    <defs>
        <filter id="img1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" >
            <feImage xlink:href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2016/06/22/gettyimages-467390112_custom-e8fa0c9a7224b7172555577fde25a08949bde2d2-s900-c85.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"/>
             <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
          </filter>
    </defs>
        <polygon points="0 100, 50,50 100,100" id="abajo"  filter="url(#img1)" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specified that what I want to do is having four triangles at every side of the screen, having a common vertex on the center, something like this http://headtag.mx/OP/ but here they are using an image that interchange when hover and that casuses bad behavior on slow networks. Thank you so much.

Comment: Upvote, but actually I think that only the last snippet can accomplish what @LuisFernandoTorreblancaMaca wants. https://jsfiddle.net/vre3vgk5/

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have checked on a larger screen and the image is enlarging :(

Comment: Please ask a new question with what you're actually trying to solve with source code that matches. This answer is a complete answer to the question that you asked here.